# Triangulated category with finitely many indecomposables and all objects have period 4

Tags: rt.representation-theory, triangulated-categories

Let a triangulated category always mean k-linear over a field k and locally finite and Krull-Schmidt in the following.
Is there a list of triangulated categories with finitely many indecomposables where all objects have period at most 4? Is there such a trinagulated category, which is not isomorphic to the stable category of a selfinjective representation-finite algebra? Is there such a triangulated category with the property that $S^4$ is not isomorphic to the identity, where $S$ is the suspension functor? Note that the stable category of penny-farthing algebras with 2 simple modules have the property that $\Omega^{3}(M) \cong M$ for all $M$ but the algebra is 6 periodic and not 3 periodic. But maybe the number 4 makes things different.